# JBoss Apache Configuration Issues

Tags: apache, jboss, jboss-eap-6

I have the following Apache configuration. I have issue like DB connection goes for toss. I have database JNDI pool entry in my web.xml for the datasource configured in `standalone.xml`

```
<resource-ref id="ResourceRef_xxxxxxxxxxx7711">
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/pcbDB</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <jndi-name>java:/jdbc/pcbDB</jndi-name>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

`standlone.xml` configuration for datasource

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/jdbc/pcbDB" pool-name="pcbdb" enabled="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))</connection-url>
                    <driver>com.oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>3</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                    </pool>
.....
</datasource>
```

Apache Configuration (defaults);

```
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>


<IfModule worker.c>
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
```

5 concurrent click on one `.war` module makes `java:/jdbc/pcbDB` makes not accessible because of `<max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>`

I will be correcting the code for the same.

My concern is when this happens, afterwards Apache needs to be restarted. Is that how it should be....

Else I can fix Apache config. by correcting `<IfModule prefork.c>` and `<IfModule worker.c>`

Please advise......

Comment: `JBoss Application Console` -> `DataSources` -> `JNDI Pool Entry` -> `Pool Tab Section` -> `Flush Button` click brings JBoss back operational..... Needs to check with Apache Integration....

Comment: Although I bring up `JBoss` when DB Connection Max Pool Size Exceeded by flushing the pool.... as because the live session had gone for toss..... `Apache` restart is required.

Comment: At the most I'm getting 502 Error described in this discussion... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981164/apache-configuration-issue-with-jboss-bad-request-from-jboss

Comment: Other than that I've given optimal limited version of config for `<IfModule prefork.c>` `<IfModule worker.c>` that **UNIX** box withstands for its configurations as per `/proc`

Comment: Correcting statement mistakenly passed.... ***Apache restart is not required at all.............*** In my case JBoss is crashing due to several code and db connectivity related issues....

Answer (score 0):

Considering the problems posted here & the same under link

[Apache Configuration Issue with JBoss [Bad Request from JBoss]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31981164/apache-configuration-issue-with-jboss-bad-request-from-jboss)

I had reconfigured datasource poll counts and `flush-strategy`.

```
            <pool>
                <min-pool-size>11</min-pool-size>
                <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
                <use-strict-min>true</use-strict-min>
                <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
            </pool>
```

Hope `<use-strict-min>` goes well.

Comment: Please don't make `min-poo-size` to `strict`..... it makes the application slow... so it should be `<use-strict-min>false</use-strict-min>`.... I had reconfigured in webconsole, now the application as like faster how it was earlier.... I hope the count 11 to `min-pool-size` is more but `$top` command results are good and fine, so taking that up....!