# Apache Configuration Issue with JBoss [Bad Request from JBoss]

Tags: apache, jboss, proxy, reverse-proxy, worker

Getting this error while open-up the web-app.

```
>502 Proxy Error
>
>Proxy Error
>The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
>The proxy server could not handle the request POST /login.do.
>
>Reason: Error reading from remote server
>
>
>
>--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
>
>Apache/2.2.15 (Red Hat) Server at 10.252.103.77 Port 80
```

My Apache Configuration is Reverse Proxy to JBoss_App_IP with worker.c->worker thread time-out.

```
ProxyPass / http://oo.nnn.nnn.nn:8080/ timeout=60
```

Additionally I have given....

```
ServerAdvertise off
```

Here is the config.

```
Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin admin@site.com
 ServerName site.com
ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>
ServerAdvertise off
ProxyPreserveHost on
ProxyPass / http://00.nnn.nnn.nn:8080/ timeout=60
</VirtualHost>
```

Didn't work `timeout=60` config, which is basically worker thread time-out.

```
14:08:46,592 INFO  [stdout] (Periodic Recovery) DEBUG [Periodic Recovery] (HornetQXAResourceWrapper.java:79) - looking for recover at DelegatingSession [session=ClientSessionImpl [name=ca333fe5-417a-11e5-a05f-61cd0d0f3dc4, username=null, closed=false, factory = ClientSessionFactoryImpl [serverLocator=ServerLocatorImpl [initialConnectors=[TransportConfiguration(name=7ea47211-417a-11e5-a05f-61cd0d0f3dc4, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryGroupConfiguration=null], connectorConfig=TransportConfiguration(name=7ea47211-417a-11e5-a05f-61cd0d0f3dc4, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0, backupConfig=null], metaData=()]@1c9794aa] configuration [XARecoveryConfig [transportConfiguration = [TransportConfiguration(name=7ea47211-417a-11e5-a05f-61cd0d0f3dc4, factory=org-hornetq-core-remoting-impl-invm-InVMConnectorFactory) ?server-id=0], discoveryConfiguration = null, username=null, password=****]]
14:08:46,916 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,918 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,923 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,923 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,928 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,929 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,934 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,935 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,940 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:32) - Inside Param Filter Class
14:08:46,945 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:56) - Suspicious Param name found :false
14:08:46,950 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:58) - Request forwarding to further Process
14:08:46,956 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,960 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,967 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,967 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,973 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,974 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,979 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,980 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,986 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,986 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,992 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,993 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (TransactionBatchingManager.java:77) - endBatch(): rolling back batch
14:08:46,999 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:85) - In getParameterMethodNames method
14:08:47,005 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:93) - Param : password
14:08:47,010 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:93) - Param : username
14:08:47,015 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:93) - Param : LoginButton
14:08:47,020 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:93) - Param : y
14:08:47,025 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9)  INFO [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (ParamFilter.java:93) - Param : x
14:08:47,030 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (LoginAction.java:95) - User <PCB_Admin> is from IP <10.252.103.77>, and IIS authentication is <false>
14:08:47,036 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:08:47,037 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:279) - pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:08:47,045 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmUserDaoImpl.java:928) - Executing SELECT USER_ID, GROUP_ID, STATUS, CREATE_DATE, USER_NAME, PASSWORD, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, EMAIL, LAST_LOGIN_DATE, LAST_PASSWORD_CHANGE_DATE, FAILED_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, IP_ALLOWED FROM UM_USER WHERE UPPER(USER_NAME) = UPPER(?) and status <> 'C'
14:08:47,062 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmUserGroupDaoImpl.java:814) - Executing SELECT GROUP_ID, GROUP_NAME, DISPLAY_NAME, PASSWORD_AGING, USER_NAME_FORMAT, PASSWORD_FORMAT, MAX_LOGIN_ATTEMPTS, SESSION_TIMEOUT, INTRANET_ACCESS, CHANGE_PASSWORD_FIRST_LOGIN FROM UM_USER_GROUP WHERE GROUP_ID = ?
14:08:47,084 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmTransactionDaoImpl.java:738) - Executing SELECT TRANSACTION_TYPE, NAME, OPERATION, DISPLAY_NAME, URL, TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID, DISPLAY_ORDER FROM UM_TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE = ?
14:08:47,095 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmTransactionDaoImpl.java:738) - Executing SELECT TRANSACTION_TYPE, NAME, OPERATION, DISPLAY_NAME, URL, TRANSACTION_GROUP_ID, DISPLAY_ORDER FROM UM_TRANSACTION WHERE TRANSACTION_TYPE = ?
14:08:47,112 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (Login.java:342) - Total time for user <PCB_Admin> executing login service = 76
14:08:47,119 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) pcbdb: returnConnection(2fc388dc, false) [0/12]
14:08:47,119 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:467) - pcbdb: returnConnection(2fc388dc, false) [0/12]
14:08:47,127 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:08:47,127 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:279) - pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:08:47,137 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmTransactionLogDaoImpl.java:243) - Executing INSERT INTO UM_TRANSACTION_LOG (TRANSACTION_TYPE, KEY_TYPE, KEY_VALUE, USER_NAME, DATE_TIME, STATUS, PARAMETERS) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?) with values: com.singtel.um.dto.TransactionLogDto: transactionType='3001', keyType='2', keyValue='PCB_Admin', userName='PCB_Admin', dateTime='Thu Aug 13 14:08:47 SGT 2015', status='O', parameters='User ID: PCB_Admin
14:08:47,151 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) ', remark='null'
14:08:47,164 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (UmTransactionLogDaoImpl.java:249) - 1 rows affected (37 ms)
14:08:47,169 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) pcbdb: returnConnection(482cbb51, false) [0/12]
14:08:47,170 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:467) - pcbdb: returnConnection(482cbb51, false) [0/12]
14:08:47,177 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) DEBUG [http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9] (LoginAction.java:120) - === in else when session is null
14:08:47,182 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) UserSession::setUserName::PCB_Admin session::org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@65b015bc
14:08:47,188 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) UserSession::validate:session::org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@65b015bc
14:08:47,366 DEBUG [org.hornetq.core.server] (hornetq-expiry-reaper-thread) Cannot expire from jms.queue.ExpiryQueue into jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
14:08:47,367 INFO  [stdout] (hornetq-expiry-reaper-thread) DEBUG [hornetq-expiry-reaper-thread] (QueueImpl.java:1470) - Cannot expire from jms.queue.ExpiryQueue into jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
14:08:47,373 INFO  [stdout] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-13) Menu.jsp:session::org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@65b015bc
14:08:56,618 DEBUG [org.jboss.ejb.client.txn] (Periodic Recovery) Send recover request for transaction origin node identifier 1 to EJB receiver with node name bdk-dev-cbsmsbl-app-01
14:09:03,238 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-12) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:09:29,165 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.idle.IdleRemover] (IdleRemover) Notifying pools, interval: 150000
14:09:39,356 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-2) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:09:52,366 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-9) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:09:54,736 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-3) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:10:08,606 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-10) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:12:41,925 DEBUG [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-15) pcbdb: getConnection(null, WrappedConnectionRequestInfo@23d59f48[userName=cbsmsbldev]) [0/12]
14:14:21,394 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.clustering.web.impl] (http-/xx.xxx.xxx.xx:8080-16) endBatch(): rolling back batch
```

Please advise.

If require I can furnish any more configs. needed over here.....

Answer (score 0):

Answered my own two queries.....

[JBoss Apache Configuration Issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31912652/jboss-apache-configuration-issues/31981788#31981788)

I hope does it solves this 502 error, as at the behind it's set of db roll-backs for transactions processing requests instead of give so response or invalid by....!